# webpack generate file with hash and include it somewhere in the app

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

In the webpack config, I use my own custom plugin to generate the file and put it into the assets.

Let's say I generate this file and call it: `test.json`. Somewhere in the app, I do this:

`axios.get('test.json')`

What I want to achieve is have the hash for this file. but If I generate this file with a hash, then I won't be able to include it via axios in the app since I won't know the hash.

One way to achieve this is when generating the file with hash, hash should be stored in the global settings(as in env).. and then use that. But the problem is I generate other files like `test.json` too. So I won't be able to store all of them in env.

Any easy way or best practice from webpack's perspective ?

Comment: I've never tried to do what you are trying to do, but you can try [this](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/) loader. You can then use webpack's [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports)